# Adding a Quarter column every three months in a report in SSRS

Tags: ssrs, business-intelligence

This is driving me a bit bonkers. It seems like it should be easy but SSRS has me stumped.

I want to create a report of our customers displaying the monthly sales totals and display the Quarter totals at the end of  every third month, e.g.

> Customer       Jan Feb Mar **Quarter1**  Apr May Jun **Quarter2** Jul
>   Aug...

I'm new to SSRS and I've created the report with the Quarter totals and the far right end, but I can place my finger on how to do it every three months.

Searching the web has not really helped me produce a solution. If you can give me insights, I'd appreciate it.

***UPDATE***
My data exists in one table. Here is the query:

```
SELECT customer
    , customercode
    , city
    , state
    , salesperson
    , invoiceYear
    , invoiceMonth 
    , CAST(SUM(netSalesValue + discValue) / 1000 AS decimal(10, 1)) AS grossSales
    , CASE WHEN invoiceMonth BETWEEN 1 AND 3 
             THEN 'Q1' 
           WHEN invoiceMonth BETWEEN 4 AND 6 
             THEN 'Q2' 
           WHEN invoiceMonth BETWEEN 7 AND 9
             THEN 'Q3'
           WHEN invoiceMonth BETWEEN 10 AND 12 
              THEN 'Q4' 
        END AS QuarterPeriod 
    , Sync 

    FROM orderstable 
    WHERE (Sync = 1) 
        AND (invoiceYear = @InvoiceYear) 

    GROUP BY invoiceYear
           , invoiceMonth
           , salesperson
           , customer
           , customercode
           , city
           , state
           , Sync 

    ORDER BY salesperson
           , customer
           , invoiceMonth
```

My query results are as follows:

```
Customer Name | 0000305 | Orange | CA | SalesPerson Name | 2015 | 1 | 8.4 | Q1 | True
```

A screenshot of my report is attached.[image: SSRS Report]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you please edit your question to include table schema and relationships.

Comment: How are you calculating the Quarter value? "On the fly" in the report definition, or as part of your query that feeds the 'base' dataset?

Comment: Quarter is derived in the query from a case statement. I've pivoted on invoice month (which is 1,2,3,4,...n) but I don't understand pivot enough to add the quarter column to it.

Comment: Gracias for the edit Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue. 
Using the following result set, 
[image: dataset]

I created a Quarter Parent column group and a Month Child column group. 
[image: grouping]

In the report, I added the quarter and month columns and their totals. <> is the formatting expression

[image: report]

The result is exactly what I was looking for.

[image: full report]